# react-native HMR not working for non-component code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hot-module-replacement

`lib.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const log = () => {
  console.log('hello');
};

class MyText extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    );
  }
}

export { log, MyText };
```

`index.ios.js`:

```
import { log, MyText } from './lib';
...
  onPressLog() {
    log();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPressLog} style={{padding: 20, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Call Log</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <MyText></MyText>
      </View>
    );
  }
...
```

Hot reloading works for changes of `MyText` but not `log`.

I'm not sure if this is not supported or a bug, please help.

Environment: OS X 10.10.5, node 6.2.1, react-native 0.28

Comment: Have you tried to put the log in a separate file?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did at first, then I add a component in it to demonstrate it how component works but regular functions doesn't.